# Compiling the right version of Python from source

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, shared-libraries, linux-mint

I have downloaded the `Python 2.7.11` source. I compile it on Linux Mint 17.3 using

```
./configure --prefix /usr/local/lib/python2.7.11 --enable-ipv6 --enable-shared
make -j 16
sudo make install
```

After that I go to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7.11/bin` and I did `./python -V`. I obtain `Python 2.7.6` which is the wrong version.

I try again to build the source without `--enable-shared`. It works fine (right version of Python) but I don't obtain the shared library. The issue is that I need the shared library associated to `Python 2.7.11`...

Any idea?